# Fetching Element From Array php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array.

```
Array
(
    [18-08-2020] => Array
        (
            [vaccination Names] => Array
                (
                    [0] => DPT
                    [1] => Polio
                    [2] => MMR
                )

        )
)
```

I need the Date `[18-08-2020]`.how do I refer to it without doing `$array['18-08-2020']`.

I need to get the date as well as elements inside it.

Comment: Well, you can loop the array? I'm not sure I understand your question, none the less, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm looping the array but the loop (foreach) takes me to vaccination names

Comment: `foreach ( $array as $date => $subarray) {}`

Comment: array_keys() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date with `array_keys();` function...

And here's how?

```
// Here is your array assigned to a variable
$myArr = array
(
    '18-08-2020' => array
        (
            'vaccination Names' => array
                (
                    0 => 'DPT',
                    1 => 'Polio',
                    2 => 'MMR'
                )

        )
);

$date = array_keys($myArr);

echo $date[0];
```

You'll get this in result:

```
18-08-2020
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

if your array has multiple instances you can go for a loop,

```
foreach( $your_array as $key => $value ){
    // $key is your date
    // $value is elements inside it
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch keys then `array_keys` will be used.

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

For values of the array then `array_values` will be used.

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

**OR**

```
$abc = Array
(
    [18-08-2020] => Array
        (
            [vaccination Names] => Array
                (
                    [0] => DPT
                    [1] => Polio
                    [2] => MMR
                )

        )
)  

foreach( $abc as $key => $value ){

}
```

Here, `$key` is your date and `$value` is elements inside it.

Thanks.